# Why do I have to run mongod as root?

Tags: mongodb

When I run "/usr/bin/mongod --config /var/data/rs1/rs1db0v3.conf". It failes. The error is:

> warning: bind_ip of 0.0.0.0 is unnecessary; listens on all ips by default
> about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
> forked process: 16970
> ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1

The permission of the relative files and folds are following:

> drwxr-xr-x 6 root    root     115 Mar 16 14:47 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root      43 Jan 20 12:12 ..
>
> drwxr-xr-x 6 mongodb mongodb 4096 Mar 16 15:05 db
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root      28 Jan 20 10:04 keys
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb   23 Jan 20 10:32 log
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb  593 Mar 16 14:47 rs1db0v3.conf
>
> **-rwxr-xr-x 1 mongodb mongodb 21303832 Mar  3 08:03 /usr/bin/mongod**

I found similar questions in this website, but no answers can help me...

**-----SOLVED-----**

I have no idea how to run mongod as mongodb, so I changed the ownership to user1, and then run mongod as user1. It works.

> drwxr-xr-x 6 root    root     115 Mar 16 14:47 .
>
> drwxr-xr-x 5 root    root      43 Jan 20 12:12 ..
>
> drwxr-xr-x 6 user1  mongodb 4096 Mar 16 15:05 db
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root      28 Jan 20 10:04 keys
>
> drwxr-xr-x 2 user1  mongodb   23 Jan 20 10:32 log
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 user1  mongodb  593 Mar 16 14:47 rs1db0v3.conf
>
> **-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1  mongodb 21303832 Mar  3 08:03 /usr/bin/mongod**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you run mongod as a normal user you need to make sure that the particular user has the following permissions:

1. Access to network interface ( open socket ) in order to be able to listen to connections
2. Access to the database folder. The default is accessible only by root or mongod user (/data/db)
3. Access to logging folder /var/log/mongod

All of the above are automatically set and granted for the user mongodb (mongod in earlier versions). If you take a look at /etc/init.d/mongodb you will see that the service will be stared under the user mongodb DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb} and not as root.

Comment: I checked the /etc/init.d/mongod, in it there are no USER information. I already upgraded the mongodb to 3.0.0 following the steps in [link] http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/   -------   FYI, I used chown to change the permission of log/ and data/ folds to mongodb:nmongodb. But it fails to run without sudo.... How can I check whether mongodb has the permission to netword interface.

Comment: In /etc/passwd, **mongodb:x:107:65534::/home/mongodb:/bin/false**